# Как вывести на странице статус icq?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html

Как вывести на странице в виде картинки статус icq? Находит в сети примеры, где надо просто подставить цифру и в зависимости от нее подгрузится системная картинка. Но как сделать, чтобы выводилась своя картинка? Мой дизайнер нарисовал 2 статуса: онлайн и офлайн. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Первая ссылка, найденная в сети.](http://shaman.asiadata.ru/node/331) Программное определение статуса ICQ через сервисы [icq.com](http://icq.com)

Answer (score 1):

Есть вот такое решение:

```
<?php
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://status.icq.com/online.gif?icq=VASH_NOMER_ICQ&img=27");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$stat=curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if (strstr($stat, "online0")) {
    $img_url="offline.jpg";
}

if (strstr($stat, "online1")) {
    $img_url="online.jpg";
}

if (strstr($stat, "online2")) {
    $img_url="disable.jpg";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://status.icq.com/online.gif?icq=**ICQ_NUMBER**&img=27

Comment: Упс, пардон. Невнимательно вопрос прочел )))